# wxwidgets Grid scrollbar disappears after resize of frame

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a grid which is put inside a frame. When i resize the frame, the scrollbar of the grid disappears. Ideally scrollbar should also become small along with the frame. Any idea how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Can you show the code? How big is the grid?

Comment: SetScrollbar from http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#aa842d59529f873683e55cd8392ec46e9 and also window sizing from http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_windowsizing.html